# How to increase number of folders/workspaces listed in "Open recent" in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to increase the number of folders/workspaces listed in the menu under `File` -> `Open recent`?

Answer (score 2):

You can open the searchable UI for more results by doing any of the following:

- go to `File` > `Open recent` > `More...`
- open the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) and use the "File: Open Recent..." command
- use the keyboard shortcut (<kbd>ctrl+r</kbd>)

If the searchable UI doesn't fit your use case, you can try upvoting and commenting on [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/8682#issuecomment-328331565).

Comment: Thanks for the instructions, I really missed the "More ..." link because it is below the files list which I never use. The issue got an upvote though, because _that's_ what I am looking for.